# Laravel Artisan can talk to MySQL but Laravel web page cannot?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5, laravel-artisan

I have a new VM running ubuntu(16.04)/apache(2.4)/php(7.2)/mysql(5.7) and I have installed Laravel 5.5.latest.

I have set up db connection details in .env file. (which are correct as I can use them to connect in mysql on the command line)

Laravel artisan can talk to the DB because my migrations have worked (I can see the tables from mysql on the command line)

But Laravel web pages cannot access the db, complaining that table db_name.table_name does not exist.

I've put in some debug into the page and it dumps the correct .env db settings.

Any idea why the db works from Artisan on the CLI but not via web pages?

Stack trace:

```
[2020-01-07 22:48:07] local.ERROR: SQLSTATE[42S02]: 
Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'SITE.property_types' doesn't exist
(SQL: select * from `property_types` where `parent_id` is null) 
{"exception":"[object] (Illuminate\\Database\\QueryException(code: 42S02):
 SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 
Table 'SITE.property_types' doesn't exist 
(SQL: select * from `property_types` where `parent_id` is null) at 
/vagrant/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:6 4, 
PDOException(code: 42S02): SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found:
 1146 Table 'SITE.property_types' doesn't exist at 
/vagrant/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:326)

[stacktrace]
#0 /vagrant/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php(624): Illuminate\\Database\\Connection->runQueryCallback('select * from `...', Array, Object(Closure))
#1 /vagrant/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php(333): Illuminate\\Database\\Connection->run('select * from `...', Array, Object(Closure))
#2 /vagrant/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.php(1719): Illuminate\\Database\\Connection->select('select * from `...', Array, true)
#3 /vagrant/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.php(1704): Illuminate\\Database\\Query\\Builder->runSelect()
#4 /vagrant/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.php(481): Illuminate\\Database\\Query\\Builder->get(Array)
#5 /vagrant/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.php(465): Illuminate\\Database\\Eloquent\\Builder->getModels(Array)
#6 /vagrant/app/Http/Controllers/BaseController.php(101): Illuminate\\Database\\Eloquent\\Builder->get()
#7 /vagrant/app/Http/Controllers/BaseController.php(48): App\\Http\\Controllers\\BaseController->buildCategoryNav()
#8 /vagrant/app/Http/Controllers/StaticController.php(40): App\\Http\\Controllers\\BaseController->__construct(Object(App\\propertyArea), Object(App\\propertyType))
#9 [internal function]: App\\Http\\Controllers\\StaticController->__construct(Object(App\\Property), Object(App\\propertyArea), Object(App\\propertyType))
#10 /vagrant/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(785): ReflectionClass->newInstanceArgs(Array)
#11 /vagrant/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(631): Illuminate\\Container\\Container->build('App\\\\Http\\\\Contro...')
#12 /vagrant/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(586): Illuminate\\Container\\Container->resolve('App\\\\Http\\\\Contro...', Array)
#13 /vagrant/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php(732): Illuminate\\Container\\Container->make('App\\\\Http\\\\Contro...', Array)
#14 /vagrant/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Route.php(226): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Application->make('App\\\\Http\\\\Contro...')
#15 /vagrant/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Route.php(796): Illuminate\\Routing\\Route->getController()
#16 /vagrant/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Route.php(757): Illuminate\\Routing\\Route->controllerMiddleware()
#17 /vagrant/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(671): Illuminate\\Routing\\Route->gatherMiddleware()
#18 /vagrant/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(651): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->gatherRouteMiddleware(Object(Illuminate\\Routing\\Route))
#19 /vagrant/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(635): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->runRouteWithinStack(Object(Illuminate\\Routing\\Route), Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#20 /vagrant/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(601): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->runRoute(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Illuminate\\Routing\\Route))
#21 /vagrant/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(590): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->dispatchToRoute(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#22 /vagrant/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(176): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->dispatch(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#23 /vagrant/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(30): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel->Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#24 /vagrant/vendor/fideloper/proxy/src/TrustProxies.php(56): Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#25 /vagrant/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(149): Fideloper\\Proxy\\TrustProxies->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#26 /vagrant/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#27 /vagrant/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/TransformsRequest.php(30): Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#28 /vagrant/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(149): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TransformsRequest->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#29 /vagrant/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#30 /vagrant/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/TransformsRequest.php(30): Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#31 /vagrant/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(149): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TransformsRequest->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#32 /vagrant/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#33 /vagrant/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/ValidatePostSize.php(27): Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#34 /vagrant/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(149): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\ValidatePostSize->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#35 /vagrant/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#36 /vagrant/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/CheckForMaintenanceMode.php(46): Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#37 /vagrant/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(149): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\CheckForMaintenanceMode->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#38 /vagrant/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#39 /vagrant/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(102): Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#40 /vagrant/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(151): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->then(Object(Closure))
#41 /vagrant/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(116): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#42 /vagrant/public/index.php(55): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#43 {main}
```

Comment: show stacktrace

Comment: Command to do that in Laravel?

Comment: Yes, and attach to the question

Comment: Added but the formatting is a bit naff, sorry

Comment: Have you verified the `property_types` table is used in the artisan command and does exists in the db?

Comment: Yes it definitely exists, the artisan migrate command created all the tables. I can go into mysql on the cli, use the database and select from that table, it has no records yet but exists and is accessible by the user/pass combo in my Laravel env file

Comment: OK this was fixed (I think) by setting bind address to 0.0.0.0 in mysql config. I thought that was already done but my provisioning script was for a different Linux version and that config had moved so wasn't set correctly.

Answer (score 1):

We had this issue today, and the solution turned out to be restarting `php artisan serve` after changing `.env` file.

If that doesn't help, you can also try:

```
php artisan config:clear
php artisan config:cache
```